# Hook URL-Navigating with Run (Win + R) method?

Tags: c#, .net, easyhook

Is there any way to hook specific URL navigating with "Run" method (Win + R)?

It means, if user opened "http://osu.ppy.sh/b/000000" with something like `Process.Start()` or etc, then my application cancel Browser navigating, and doing some stuffs (with "000000" parameter) in my application.

I poorly tried something like configuring `HKCR` registry or something, but it doesn't work.

(Similar with [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx), but with full-URL, not protocols.)

Edit) Or any chance to hook specific program's "Run" attempt to browse webpage?